# Custom RPC Kerberos authentication working on Samba but dont Windows

Tags: windows, samba, kerberos, rpc

I have implemented an RPC client in C# which uses GSS/SPNEGO authentication. I am trying to connect to the standard/Active Directory services (DRSAPI, SAMR etc...) on the server. The authentication works fine except when using Kerberos authentication and I've been struggling for 1 week now trying to troubleshoot the error. The use cases are the following:

Samba NTLM => OK

Samba Kerberos => OK

Windows NTLM => OK

Windows (2012, 2016) Kerberos => KO

When trying Kerberos, the authentication to the KDC seems to work just fine, the ticket is obtained, but when trying to connect to the RPC service, the server respond with a [nca_s_fault_sec_pkg_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYULr.png) (again, only on Windows 2012) and I can't find what is rubbing Windows the wrong way. I am not an expert in Kerberos and there doesn't seem to be any entry in the event viewer. I compared Wireshark traces with a working and non working authentication and I can't see any differences.

Can someone please help me identify what the error is? Let me know if you need more information, I can provide Network traces and logs (samba, app, windows)

[Here is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/25zpz2mw1dt70znv9vni0/Kerberos_Auth.zip?rlkey=64qcaoinw3syufo9e76gacm3g&dl=0) to working (Samba) and non working (Windows 2012) wireshark traces of the exact same code with only the user password and the address of the server (Samba = 192.168.1.49 and W2K12 = 192.168.1.151) as differences

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds like a programming/software dev question for stack overflow

Comment: @Gantendo I asked and they redirected me here. I don't think it is a programming error since it seems to be windows that is rejecting the RPC connection, but the problem is I can't figure out why since there is no errors in the even log. I guess the question is more how to get an error at the windows level

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using a ticket for the `ldap/…` service with something that is not LDAP? Yes, it's true that all the service principals share a single machine key in AD, but that has led to some _major_ security issues over time, and I believe Windows will nowadays specifically prevent you from using a ticket for the wrong principal even if the key matches. Please retry with the correct SPN.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, I genuinely don't know what should be the SPN for DRSUAPI, I went with ldap because that was the SPN used by other windows native client for this services, but if you have a specific one in mind I'd be happy to try it.